# String contains another string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

How can I check if a string contains another string instead of using "==" to compare the whole string?

Regards

Comment: Here a benchmark for the most common ways to check if a string is in a string: http://jsben.ch/#/o6KmH

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You can use [**`.indexOf()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
if(str.indexOf(substr) > -1) {

}
```

Comment: didn't work when I use msgCache[id].headers.subject.indexOf("DELIVERY FAILURE:") > -1

Comment: and the subject is: DELIVERY FAILURE: User fdfd.ablfdfitt (df.fdf@dfdf.com) not listed in Domino Directory

Comment: Well, what is `msgCache[id].headers.subject`?

Comment: it returns "DELIVERY FAILURE: User fdfd.ablfdfitt (df.fdf@dfdf.com) not listed in Domino Directory"

Comment: @donald: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bZUvp/ (and it also works with node.js, it's the same JavaScript)

Comment: Actually, the message is inside an array [ 'DELIVERY FAILURE: User fdfd.ablfdfitt (df.fdf@dfdf.com) not listed in Domino Directory' ] sorry for the mistake.

Comment: str.indexOf() works better than str.search(). Anyone knows why?